# find file names by searching the last lines for pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have to find all files in a large number of large ASCII files which contain a specific pattern. At the moment I'm doing that with

```
grep -l <pattern> <files>
```

and it's very slow.
But I know that the pattern appears in the last 10 lines, if it exists. Is there an elegant possibility to search only the last lines to speed up the search, e.g. with awk?

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstand sth., but if I use tail and pipe the output to grep, I can't get the file name, because the input for grep is from  standard input.

Comment: pipes are slow, use better files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply print the filename while processing

```
for f in $files; do
  echo "---- File \"$f\" ------"
  tail -n 10 "$f" | grep -l "$pattern"
  # you can also save the stdout to $f...
done
```

Comment: Or: `tail -n 10 "$f" | grep -q "$pattern" && echo "$f"`

Comment: Thx for the quotes, I don't know how I could forgot :D Also I want to use his grep syntax and echo the name before the file :)

Answer (score 1):

to see only specific number of line of a file then command syntex is as follow.

`tail [+ number] [-l] [-b] [-c] [-r] [-f] [-c number | -n number] [file]`

Now you can use pipe to comand `greap` and cat to perform your specific work.

i.e.

`tail -n 10 <fileName>|grep -l <pattern> <files>`

[Click here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm) to know more.

Comment: But if I pipe the output of grep to any other command, in this case tail, what prevents grep from searching every single line of every single file?